# When to say shehecheyanu on a new fruit?

Tags: halacha, blessing, fruits, shehecheyanu

[Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 225:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.225.3?lang=bi) records that the custom is to recite the *shehecheyanu* blessing on a new fruit when one eats it.

At what point precisely does one say *shehecheyanu*? Before reciting *borei peri haeitz*? After reciting *borei peri haeitz* but before eating of the fruit? After eating some of the fruit?

Comment: While this question is about following the custom, as noted in the shulchan arukh there you can say it already when you see it without any loss.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Halachipedia](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shehecheyanu) has a good rundown and explains as follows:

> **When to make the Bracha**
>
> ---
>
> According to some it is preferable to say Shehecheyanu before the Bracha on the fruit, however, the minhag is to make the Bracha on the food and then the Shehecheyanu.<sup>1</sup>
>
> One only makes a bracha on the first time one eats the fruit (that year).<sup>2</sup>
>
> If one forgot to make the Bracha before eating, one may make it as long as one has not finish eating;<sup>3</sup> however once one finished, one can’t make a Shehecheyanu on that fruit.<sup>4</sup>

---

> <sup>1</sup> [Halachot Ketanot 1:236](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=723&st=&pgnum=48&hilite=) writes that perhaps it is
> best to recite Shehechiyanu before the bracha on the food so that
> Shechiyanu isn't an interruption between the bracha and eating.
> However, he concludes that he should say it earlier like we do for
> Lulav and Shofar that first we recite the Bracha of the Mitzvah and
> then the Shehechiyanu. [Kaf Hachaim 225:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.225.24.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) cites both opinions but
> concludes that the minhag is like the Halachot Ketanot to recite the
> Shehechiyanu after. [Halacha Brurah 225:24](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=162141&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16091555989699682&pagenum=366) and [Yalkut Yosef
> 225:9](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=170235&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16091555989699682&pagenum=100) agree. [Mishna Brurah 225:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.225.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that it’s preferable
> to say Shehecheyanu first in order not to make an interruption between
> the Bracha and eating. However, [Vezot HaBracha (pg 159)](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=622101&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16091555989699682&pagenum=182) writes
> that the minhag is to make the Bracha on the fruit first.
>
> <sup>2</sup> [Mishna Brurah 225:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.225.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
>
> <sup>3</sup> [Yalkut Yosef 225:8](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=170235&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16091555989699682&pagenum=100)
>
> <sup>4</sup> [Mishna Brurah 225:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.225.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Halacha Brurah 225:23](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=162141&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16091555989699682&pagenum=362),
> Sh"t Besel Chachma 5:27, [Vezot HaBracha (pg 160)](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=622101&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16091555989699682&pagenum=183) quoting Rav
> Elyashiv

---

**EDIT**

In addition, in HaRav Chaim Bleier's weekly 'Chukei Chaim' halacha series (Parshas Beshalach 5781 - [no. 211](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yo0ySTIiyYsAGpkldZup_2tptb-sRyZr/view?usp=sharing)) he notes as follows:

> Some say that lechatchila, one should say Shehecheyanu before Ha’eitz so that Shehecheyanu, which is optional, does not interrupt between the Ha'eitz and the eating between (פמ"ג ח"א כלל ס"ב ס"ח, מ"ב סקי"א, מנהג חת"ס). Nevertheless, if one made Shehecheyanu second, he is yotzei bedieved.
>
> Others say that one should say Ha’eitz and then Shehecheyanu before eating since Ha’eitz is tadir [more frequently said]. It is not an interruption since we accepted it upon ourselves as an obligation (באר היטב סק"ו, שו"ת אבני נזר או"ח סי' ת"נ, כף החיים סקכ"ד שכן נוהגים אחינו בני הספרדים). **This is the commonly accepted custom**.